# Which formula to use if I were to compare values from multiple columns with corresponding values within a named range?

Tags: arrays, join, google-sheets, vlookup, textjoin

Example [sheet link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/14Dy-VKL7xHlH5KpZnJkWjNPDM6g5lkKZReakyJGTdj0/edit#gid=0).

I'm fairly new to sheet and I was wondering if I should be using vlookup or dget for such case based on the sheet link above:

1. I have values for Column A, B, C,
2. I have a named range (A2:C8)
3. I have drop down table for Column E (based on Column A values) and Column F (based on Column B values)

So if I wanted Column G to return Column C value by comparing Column E&F values with Column A&B values and find the matching combination, should I be using vlookup or dget?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use:

```
=INDEX(IFNA(VLOOKUP(E3:E&"×"&F3:F, {A:A&"×"&B:B, C:C}, 2, 0)))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this formula in one of your cells. I included in your worksheet.

```
=filter(C3:C8,B3:B8=F3,A3:A8=E3)
```

Comment: thank you! this helped to get the general idea of how to use filter along.